# Call web url using Unix

Tags: unix, url

i am new into UNIX shell scripting. i have assignment to create Autosys job which further calls servlet url. i think it will go through unix shell scripting.
Can you provide me steps to implement this feature?

Comment: Checkout `wget` and/or `curl`.

Comment: Step one: read the Stack overflow help center to understand what makes up a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Write a bash script with the CuRL calls to your server and then call this using AutoSys.

JIL File Example:

```
 /* ----------------- job_name ----------------- */ 

  update_job: job_name      job_type: CMD 
  command: . /home/../mybashScript.sh "param1Value" "param2Value"
  machine: machine.domain.com 
  owner: username
 /* Other Parameters like profile, date conditions etc. */
```

CuRL Call Example:

MethodType can be POST/GET.

```
curl -w "\n" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X $methodtype -d '{"param1": "'$param1Value'", "param2": "'$param2Value'"}' http://$server:$port/$servicename/$methodname
```